# how can i have child values in the form of comma delimited list?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have one table where in I am adding parent and child values in same column but differentiating them with `parentid`  like parent value will not have `parentid` it will only have auto incremented `id` and the child values will have both auto incremented Ids as well as parentid the `parentid` which is equal to the id of parent value.

here is my table

```
id    parentid     q_values
1       0          parentvalue
2       1          childvalue
3       1          childvalue
4       1          childvalue
```

can anyone help me out how can i have child values in the form of comma delimited list ?

and I have tried this but no success.

```
SELECT 
     q_values,  
     GROUP_CONCAT( CASE WHEN parentid = id THEN q_values END ) AS childvalue,
FROM table_name
```

The result should look like this

```
id     q_values           childvalue
1    parentValue    childvalues, childvalues
```

Comment: What should the result look like? And note that orphans are conventionally represented by NULL, not 0.

Comment: @Strawberry - i have updated my question. By default we kept that Null because it doesn't accept Null values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to

1. Self-join
2. add a `GROUP BY` clause because GROUP_CONCAT is an aggregate function

This is closer to your solution

```
SELECT p.q_values as parentvalue,  
     GROUP_CONCAT(c.q_values) AS childvalue,
FROM table_name AS p
JOIN table_name AS c
  ON p.id = c.parentid
WHERE p.parentid = 0
GROUP BY parentvalue
ORDER BY parentvalue
```

Answer (score 0):

For the GROUP_CONCAT to work, You must have GROUP BY in your query.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat